# What is the significance of [DataContract][Serializable] & [DataMember] in our model for EF Code First Approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, serialization, ef-code-first

Does this have any adverse effects on our CRUD operations?

[image: Image of EF Model]

Is there a significant difference if we don't use these attributes in our model?

Comment: Please post you code as **CODE**-Block instead of an image. It helps us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a significant difference if you dont use the attributes.

See: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts